# Getting current value from Stream

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

There is a StreamBuilder (using RxDart) which displays some date. After click on InkWell widget I need to calculate a new date on basis of old one. The code below simply explains the algo but when I run it there is nothing happens and execution stops after underlined row, i.e. I never see the value of **lastCalcDate**.

GUI:

```
child: StreamBuilder(
  stream: bloc.getDate,
  builder: (context,snapshot) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => tapHandler
    );
}),

void tapHandler() async {
  var lastCalcDate = await bloc.getDate.single;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  print(lastCalcDate);
  var newCalcDate = lastCalcDate.add(Duration(days:1));
  bloc.setDate(newCalcDate)
}
```

BLoC:

```
class Bloc {
  // BehaviourSubject is usedto be sure that last sent date will be accessible in `tapHandler`.
  final _dateSubject = BehaviourSubject<DateTime>(); 
  Observable<DateTime> get getDate => _dateSubject.stream;
  Function(DateTime) get setDate => _dateSubject.add;
}
```

To implement what I need I created some workaround but I don't like it because I fill that I can do the same thing using observables.

BLoC (workaround):

```
class Bloc {
  final _dateSubject = BehaviourSubject<DateTime>(); 
  Observable<DateTime> get getDate => _dateSubject.stream;
  DateTime _date;
  void setDateWorkaround(DateTime date) {
    _date = date;
    _dateSubject.add(date);
  }
}
```

Could you someone to give me advise. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`single` will not work because it is going to return the next item in the stream, however, that has to be added first. This means that `single` will just wait for the next item and in your case it will not happen.

Since you are using `rxdart` and `BehaviorSubject` already, you can easily access the current element like this:

```dart
class Bloc {
  final _dateSubject = BehaviourSubject<DateTime>(); 
  Observable<DateTime> get getDate => _dateSubject.stream;
  Function(DateTime) get setDate => _dateSubject.add;

  DateTime get currentDate => _dateSubject.value;
}
```

In this case, I am making use of [`BehaviorSubject.value`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject/value.html), which is actually the whole point of that class.

Now, you can just use `currentDate` in your tap handler:

```dart
void tapHandler() async {
  var lastCalcDate = bloc.currentDate;
  print(lastCalcDate);
  var newCalcDate = lastCalcDate.add(Duration(days:1));
  bloc.setDate(newCalcDate)
}
```

Comment: hi, how can I get it without using rx?

Comment: If someone runs into the same issue: There seemed to be a breaking change in the rxdart package where you can not use .value directly on a BehaviorSubject anymore. You would have to use "_dateSubject.valueWrapper.value".
The link in this answer to the BeahviorSubject.value documentation is invalid now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StreamProvider` from [provider](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider)

> Listen to a Stream and expose the latest value emitted.